# Repeating Scrollspy

Tags: jquery-plugins

I used a jQueryScrollSpy (https://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspyhttps://github.com/sxalexander/jquery-scrollspy) to set it up so that when you scroll into the div #red, its respective child '.test' fadesIn. How do I set it up so that when you scroll to the top of N div, the child of N appears? (and disappears after leaving div N.)

Thank you for the help, I have never set up a loop of this sort.

Joe

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                    $(".test").hide();

                    $('#red').each(function(i) {
                        var position = $(this).position();
                        console.log(position);
                        console.log('min: ' + position.top + ' / max: ' + parseInt(position.top + $(this).height()));
                        $(this).scrollspy({
                            min: position.top,
                            max: position.top + $(this).height(),
                            onEnter: function(element, position) {
                                if(console) console.log('entering.#red');
                                $("#red").children().fadeIn(200);},

                            onLeave: function(element, position) {
                                if(console) console.log('leaving.#red');
                                $("#red").children().fadeOut(200);}

                            /*onEnter: function(element, position) {
                                if(console) console.log('entering.#blue');
                                $(".test").show();},

                            onLeave: function(element, position) {
                                if(console) console.log('leaving.#blue');
                                $(".test").hide();}*/
                        });
                    });
                });
            </script>
```